# balita theme / nivo slider transition

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the 'Balita' free ecommerce wordpress theme. It comes stock with 'nivo' slider hooked to the dashboard. This is fine, but doesn't allow slide transition customizations and is left at crazy 'random' at default. I'd like to use 'fade' but can't find where the theme is calling the jQuery.

All I see is the initiation code below; within the header.php

```
<?php
                    // get recent slider max is 5 slider.
                    tk_get_recent_posttype('slider', 1, 5);
                    if(have_posts ()):
                ?>
        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                                <?php
                                    while (have_posts ()): the_post();
                                        echo '<a href="'.  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_tk_slider_meta_link', true).'">';
                                        the_post_thumbnail('slider', array('alt' => get_the_title(), 'title' => ''));
                                        echo '</a>';
                                    endwhile;
                                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
                <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I've also tried dragging the tradtional jQuery code above this within the same head to toggle 'fade' but it ignores it. How could I change the slide transitions / where could I find the jQuery? Or am I stuck to working with a new plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the script to edit within an open source FTP client called 'script.js'. Rad, good to go.